# add a custom escape button to the editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

My tinymce editor is inside a hidden div (`#mdedit`) which I show / hide via jquery:

```
$('#mdedit').show();
$('#mdedit').hide();
```

The last (`hide`) function is binded with `esc` button on keyboard.

When editor is visible and some changes to its content are made, focus is transfered to editor (i.e. iframe) so `esc` button doesn't work.

So trying to add a custom (`esc`) button to the editor

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#texedit",
    body_class: 'tiny01',
    content_css: "content.css",
    skin: "gradient",
    setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      text: 'esc',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        $('#mdedit').hide();
      }
    });
    },
...
```

- there is no `esc` button on my toolbar
- suppossing the button is there, I'm not sure will my code `$('#mdedit').hide();` work.

Any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as documentation you can find [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/)

you didn't specify where the button will append

```
toolbar: 'mybutton'
```